# Google Drive Document

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-docs

I'm trying to implement a system by which content from a google document gets published automatically to embed in a website.  I have a spreadsheet that people put content into and then scripts run on the spreadsheet.  That script generates HTML into a Google Document.  I need to be able to get that document published online as an HTML webpage.

I'm currently using a PHP script to import an external HTML file from the web.  However, when I use the google drive host method (https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en), the page that it generates, when imported using the PHP script (below) doesn't work.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to do this?  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

```
<?php include 'https://c08c27b5f9a6a650048e1a836504c87c168e1999-www.googledrive.com/host/0B87yC_tFJClKVVhjZkh2Yy1oTm8';?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your php.ini set `allow_url_include = On` - it should do the job.

Better use: `echo file_get_contents('https://c08c27b5f9a6a650048e1a836504c87c168e1999-www.googledrive.com/host/0B87yC_tFJClKVVhjZkh2Yy1oTm8');` it will not execute php code as include would - more secure.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked to get the file into drive, but I'm still not sure how to export an HTML file from my google document so that I can work with this PHP.

Comment: use `$var = file_get_contents([url])`